# Help navigating help files

Tags: help-system

In the case below, how would I find what the definition of `[cmd]` or `[range]` or `{pattern}` is ?

[image]

I have tried `CTRL-]` with my cursor on these, but this does not do anything.

Comment: `CTRL-]` works on `[range]`, pattern is `:h pattern`, `cmd` is any `:commad` vim has (probably any?)

Comment: I am a using neovim. When I put the cursor on the first [range] in the screenshot , inside :[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd] I get error E149: Sorry, no help for: :[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]. However when I put the cursor on the second [range] in the screenshot , the one in the description,  CTRL-] does work ! Pressing CTRL-] on the second [cmd] in the screenshot takes me to a random place in the help system, whilst i get the same error as for [range] for the first.

Comment: first range is a part of a longer word `:[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]` and there is no such help tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CTRL-]` jump is tag based, meaning that it will take word under cursor and jump to the first tag matching it.

somewhere in `:help help` and `/Jump to speci<CR>`

```
Jump to specific subjects by using tags.  This can be done in two ways:
- Use the "CTRL-]" command while standing on the name of a command or option.
  This only works when the tag is a keyword.  "<C-Leftmouse>" and
  "g<LeftMouse>" work just like "CTRL-]".
- use the ":ta {subject}" command.  This also works with non-keyword
  characters.
```